# Сменил vps, перестала работать обработка русских стоп слов

Tags: php

reg_match_all("#\b".$k."(?:es|s|**ru**)?\b#usi",$txt, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER); 
из-за чего это может быть?
Версия php 5.3.3, пробовал увеличивать до 5.6 не работает.
Из-за чего на одном сервере функция работает а на другом нет?

```
<?php
class profanityFilter {
var $wordList;

function __construct() {
    $this->_setWordList();
}

function scanText($txt) {
    $profanityCount = 0;
    $txt = strip_tags($txt);
    $txt = html_entity_decode($txt,ENT_QUOTES);
    $txt=strtolower($txt);
    foreach ($this->wordList as $k=>$v) {
        preg_match_all("#\b".$k."(?:es|s|ru)?\b#si",$txt, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        $profanityCount += count($matches)*$v;
    }
    return $profanityCount;
}

function _setWordList() {
    $words = array(
            "слово"=>1,
    );
    $wordsPrepped = array();
    foreach ($words as $k=>$v) {
        $k = str_replace('-','\\W*',$k);
        $wordsPrepped[$k] = $v;
    }
    $this->wordList = $wordsPrepped;
}    
}
?>
```

Comment: Куда вы дели от сюда `"#\b".$k."(?:es|s|ru)?\b#si"` модификатор `u`?

Comment: Спасибо! Видимо удалил, случайно.

Comment: `preg_match_all("#\b".$k."(?:es|s|ru)?\b#usi",$txt, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);`  так проработало несколько часов и перестало. Опять что-то пропустил?

Comment: В лог ошибок на сервере посмотрите.